# Summation of the corresponding number of values which are in different columns

Tags: r

My data frame looks like below:

```
df<-data.frame(alphabets1=c("A","B","C","B","C"," ","NA"),alphabets2=c("B","A","D","D"," ","E","NA"),alphabets3=c("C","F","G"," "," "," ","NA"), number = c("1","2","3","1","4","1","2"))

  alphabets1 alphabets2 alphabets3 number
1          A          B          C      1
2          B          A          F      2
3          C          D          G      3
4          B          D                 1
5          C                            4
6                     E                 1
7         NA         NA         NA      2
```

**NOTE1**: within the row all the values are unique, that is, below shown is not possible.

```
  alphabets1 alphabets2 alphabets3 number
1          A          A          C      1
```

**NOTE2**: data frame may contains NA or is blank

I am struggling to get the below output: which is nothing but a dataframe which has the alphabets  and the sum of their corresponding numbers, that is **A** alphabet is in 1st and 2nd rows so its sum of its corresponding number is 1+2 i.e 3 and let's say **B**, its in 1st, 2nd and 4th row so the sum will be 1+2+1 i.e 4.

```
output <-data.frame(alphabets1=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"), number = c("3","4","8","4","1","2","3")) 

output
   alphabets number
1          A      3
2          B      4
3          C      8
4          D      4
5          E      1
6          F      2
7          G      3
```

**NOTE3:** output may or may not have the NA or blanks (it doesn't matter!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reshape it to 'long' format and do a group by operation

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.var="number", na.rm = TRUE, value.name = "alphabets1")[
   !grepl("^\\s*$", alphabets1), .(number = sum(as.integer(as.character(number)))),
                 alphabets1]
#    alphabets1 number
#1:          A      3
#2:          B      4
#3:          C      8
#4:          D      4
#5:          E      1
#6:          F      2
#7:          G      3
```

---

Or we can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(number~alphabets1, data.frame(alphabets1 = unlist(df[-4]),
              number = as.numeric(as.character(df[,4]))))
```

NOTE: In the OP's dataset, the missing values were `"NA"`, and not real `NA` and the 'number' column is `factor` (which was changed by converting to `integer` for doing the `sum`)

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(alphabets1=c("A","B","C","B","C"," ",NA),
         alphabets2=c("B","A","D","D"," ","E",NA),
         alphabets3=c("C","F","G"," "," "," ",NA), 
          number = c("1","2","3","1","4","1","2"))
```

Comment: @varun  You can also do this with `library(tidyverse);df %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., grepl("^\\s*$", .), NA)), matches("alphabets")) %>% gather(key, alphabets1, -number, na.rm = TRUE) %>% group_by(alphabets1) %>% summarise(number = sum(as.integer(as.character(number))))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method using `sapply` and `table`. I first converted `df$number` into a numeric. See data section below.

```
data.frame(table(sapply(df[-length(df)], function(i) rep(i, df$number))))
  Var1 Freq
1        11
2    A    3
3    B    4
4    C    8
5    D    4
6    E    1
7    F    2
8    G    3
9   NA    6
```

To make the output a little bit nicer, we could wrap a few more functions and perform a subsetting within `sapply`.

```
data.frame(table(droplevels(unlist(sapply(df[-length(df)],
                                     function(i) rep(i[i %in% LETTERS],
                                                     df$number[i %in% LETTERS])),
                            use.names=FALSE))))
  Var1 Freq
1    A    3
2    B    4
3    C    8
4    D    4
5    E    1
6    F    2
7    G    3
```

It may be easier to do this afterward, though.

**data**

I ran

```
df$number <- as.numeric(df$number)
```

on the OP's data resulting in this.

```
df <-
structure(list(alphabets1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
5L), .Label = c(" ", "A", "B", "C", "NA"), class = "factor"), 
    alphabets2 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c(" ", 
    "A", "B", "D", "E", "NA"), class = "factor"), alphabets3 = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c(" ", "C", "F", "G", "NA"
    ), class = "factor"), number = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2)), .Names = c("alphabets1", 
"alphabets2", "alphabets3", "number"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's showing me this  "Error in rep.default(i, df$number) : invalid 'times' argument"

Comment: I converted your `df$number` into numeric. See the bottom of my post.